# Javah Error: Could not find class file for package.name

Tags: java, java-native-interface, javah

I am trying to generate C header file for **JNI** (Linux). I read documentation and questions on `javah`, but I still get the same error

> Error: Could not find class file for 'org.sqlite.core.NativeDB'

I think I have very obvious mistake but I really don't see any... So, I need to **generate header** file from the **NativeDB.class** and the path is:

```
/u/users/maas/user123/sqlite/sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0/target/common-lib/org/sqlite/core/NativeDB.class
```

I go to the **common-lib** folder and call `javah` from the path of:

```
/u/users/maas/user123/sqlite/sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0/target/common-lib/
```

The commands I tried:

```
javah -classpath "/u/users/maas/user123/sqlite/sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0/target/common-lib/org/sqlite/core" org.sqlite.core.NativeDB
javah org.sqlite.core.NativeDB
```

The error I get:

> Error: Could not find class file for 'org.sqlite.core.NativeDB'

I see the `NativeDB.class` file in the correct directory I mentioned. In the `NativeDB.java` (which is not in the same folder with NativeDB.class IF it is important) there is a package path:

```
package org.sqlite.core;
```

Comment: Try shortening your classpath to `/u/users/maas/user123/sqlite/sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0/target/common-lib`. The intermediate directories are part of the class lookup.

Comment: @Botje thank you for the reply. I tried your suggestion but it gives the same error :(

Comment: I downloaded [the jar from maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.21.0.1), unpacked it, and `javah -cp . org.sqlite.core.NativeDB` Just Worked(tm). Not sure what else I can say.

Comment: Did you copy the command line from some documentation? Your quotes look like typographic quotation marks (Unicode 201D) instead of "normal" quotes (Unicode 0022). This way the classpath won't be recognized at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue (that was really obvious and dumb).

Commands I wrote in the question are correct. I am using USS (UNIX System Services) for Z/OS and ftp for transferring files. I didn't check that I sent .class files via ftp NOT in binary format. And for this reason Java couldn't find the classes because of wrong encoding.

All you need is just turn on the binary mode in the ftp like so:

```
ftp server.name.com
..login...
bi
mput *class
```

The `bi` command enables binary mode. The .class files are **expected** to be in this format.

Comment: FTP claims another victim. Good find!